# Extension of Inverse Function theorem to k-times continuously differentiable functions.

Tags: real-analysis, inverse-function-theorem

In an exercise, I am asked to show that

> If in the (single variable) Inverse Function Theorem $f$ has $k$ continuous derivatives, then the inverse function $g$ also has $k$ continuous derivatives.

Other posts on this forum answered a similar question using Leibniz's formula, but I have not yet learned this. I suspect that I can apply Taylor's theorem to write $f$ as its $k$th Taylor polynomial plus its remainder, since $f$ is $C^k$, but I am struggling to figure out what I should do next. Could someone please help me with how to proceed?

Thank you

Comment: I suggest doing this by induction.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut The Inverse Function Theorem requires $f'(a) \neq 0$.

Comment: Could you include the statement of the theorem as well?

Comment: Yes, this book states it as follows: Let $f:(a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function, $x_0 \in (a,b)$ where $f'(x_0) \neq 0.$ Then there exists an open interval $I \subset (a,b)$ with $x_0 \in I,$ the restriction $f\mid_I$ is injective with a continuously differentiable inverse $g: J \rightarrow I$ defined on $J = f(I),$ and $g'(y) = \frac{1}{f'(g(y))}$ for all $y\in J.$

Comment: Think about how they proved the inverse is $C^1$ when $k=1$. Now, what is true when $k=2$? Continue.